# How to get the high and low first 1 hr and 2 hr candle from market opening?

Tags: pine-script

Is there anyway to get the high and low value of the first 1 hr and 2 hr candle from market opening. I don't see any direct way to pass the timeframe into the high and low function. I want to plot the mid price, so need these values to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: On what timeframe do you want to use this?

Comment: @vitruvius 5 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is,

Convert your current timeframe into minutes. Then figure out how many bars there are in an hour and two hours on your chart. Setup two counters for that and update your high/low variables while your counter is within your limits.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

// ————— Converts current chart timeframe into a float minutes value.
f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

var high_1h = 10e-10
var low_1h = 10e10
var high_2h = 10e-10
var low_2h = 10e10

bars_1h = 60 / f_resInMinutes()     // Number of bars within an hour
bars_2h = 120 / f_resInMinutes()    // Number of bars within two hours

var cnt_1h = 0
var cnt_2h = 0

isNewMarketOpen = session.ispremarket[1] and session.ismarket

cnt_1h := isNewMarketOpen ? 0 : cnt_1h + 1  // Reset when market opens, increase otherwise
cnt_2h := isNewMarketOpen ? 0 : cnt_2h + 1  // Reset when market opens, increase otherwise

high_1h := isNewMarketOpen ? 10e-10 : high_1h
low_1h := isNewMarketOpen ? 10e10 : low_1h
high_2h := isNewMarketOpen ? 10e-10 : high_2h
low_2h := isNewMarketOpen ? 10e10 : low_2h

if (cnt_1h <= bars_1h)
    high_1h := high > high_1h ? high : high_1h
    low_1h := low < low_1h ? low : low_1h

if (cnt_2h <= bars_2h)
    high_2h := high > high_2h ? high : high_2h
    low_2h := low < low_2h ? low : low_2h

plot(high_1h, color=color.green)
plot(low_1h, color=color.red)
plot(high_2h, color=color.purple)
plot(low_2h, color=color.orange)
```

[image]

Market opens at 09:30. That's where the low is both for 1h and 2h. Then at 10:30, exactly one hour after the market opens, the prices makes a new high. That value is kept for the rest of the session as 1h high (green line). For the 2h high, you can follow the purple line.

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to figure out how to plot **Mid price** after 1hr and 2Hr.

Comment: What is the purpose of `10e10` and `10e-10` ?

Comment: I can edit my question and give you an example for the mid price if you want. Sorry, I only focused on the question.

Comment: So that you have one really high and low value variable. When you compare your price with that variable for the first time, it will definitely take the price as high/low. Then on the next iteration, you will compare the price woth the old high/low price.

Comment: I just did this `plot((low_1h + (high_1h - low_1h) / 2), style=plot.style_line, color=color.orange)`. But don't see the price line. Any idea why?

Comment: I see this https://www.tradingview.com/x/Vp1a922I/

Comment: Hm. so for me it is calculating wrong low and high.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot and show me where the calculation is wrong?

Comment: see this https://www.tradingview.com/x/Vp1a922I/ .. Mid price it calculated is not what the mid price of the stock today after 1hr.